# How does JavaScript interpreter know that an encountered function call should be treated synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: javascript

Lately, i am learning asynchronous functions in javaScript.
 I know now what callbacks are, the difference between synchronous and asynchronous, and the callback hell anti-pattern.
However, I still have a questions that makes me always feel uncomfortable with what I have already learned:

How does JavaScript interpreter know that an encountered function call should be treated synchronously or asynchronously? 
For example, if javascript interpreter encounters...

```
setTimeout(callback,5000) //Assming that callback is a callback function
```

...it runs this function in completion (in its own new stack, after the main stack is empty). However, when it encounters...

```
function myFunction(callback) { callback(); }
```

...it treats it synchronously.

Does javascript interpreter has a list of functions that should be treated asynchronously?
 And if not how does it know if an encountered function should be treated synchronously or asynchronously? 



Sorry if i did any english grammatical mistakes, and thank you in advance for helping me as usual.

Comment: `callback()` <-- Function invocations - with `(..)` - are *always* "synchronous" (even with `async`, although that's a different case). Usages, such as `setTimeout` allow "asynchronous" operations because the supplied callback is *not* invoked immediately. Rather, the callback function object [not the result of invocation] is placed on a queue to be *invoked later when the timeout expires*, thus making the `setTimeout` *operation* "asynchronous".

Comment: The `setTimeout()` call itself is also synchronous, it just uses some internal magic to queue a task that executes the provided callback...

Comment: So i should know all the asynchronous functions (like api calls, ajax, setInterval, setTimeout...), to become able to predict, if a certain function will be treated synchronously or asynchronously ?

Comment: I think this info will help you immensely: https://javascript.info/event-loop. JavaScript is largely synchronous but provides mechanisms for handling asynchronous code. Even then, a large effort has been put in to allowing you to make asynchronous code look and handle like synchronous code, thanks to `Generator`, `Promise`, and the new `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Javascript interpreter does know of functions that are asynchronous, `setTimeout` being one of them. The asynchronous behavior is handled by the underlying runtime code.

And you cannot create your own asynchronous functions without using one of the built-in asynchronous functions. Asynchronicity comes from the interpreter, which in-turn comes from the async I/O interfaces (or threads if only blocking I/O is available) exposed by the underlying OS.

Answer (score 1):

The same way it knows that `alert()` opens a dialog box and `XMLHttpRequest()` creates an object to make network requests.

Functions do what functions do.